# How to attach Visual Studio Code terminal to a podman container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, podman

I have installed the [podman CLI](https://podman.io/docs/installation) on the Ubuntu 22.04 operating system with the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install podman
```

For testing purposes, I pulled the `python:slim` docker image and then ran a new container from that image.

```
podman pull python:slim
podman run -dt python:slim
```

Now I would like to attach the Visual Studio Code terminal to the recently created container. Therefore, I installed the [docker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker) from VS Code. However, I got the following warning.

> Failed to connect. Is Docker installed?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this container?  If you installed Apache httpd through another means like, say, Homebrew, how and why would you "get a shell inside" the HTTP server?

Comment: @DavidMaze This image is only pulled because of testing purposes. The shell can be obtained because the `httpd` docker image is based from the `debian:12-slim` docker image. I will replace this example image since it seems confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Downgrade Docker Extension

To fix the problem, I had to downgrade the Docker extension to 1.22.2 version because there is a known [breaking change at the 1.23.0](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/17306) docker extension version. Downgrade the Docker extension: right-click on the **Docker** extension > select the **Install Another Version...** option > select the **1.22.2** version.

```bash
code --install-extension ms-azuretools.vscode-docker@1.22.2
```

Alternatively, you can also use the terminal to downgrade the extension.

### Configure Settings

The next step was to configure the `docker.host` and the `docker.dockerPath` variables under the settings. Before that, we need to create a docker daemon equivalent, since Podman is daemonless. It is achieved by enabling the `podman.socket` unit.

```bash
systemctl enable --now --user podman.socket
```

It exposes a Unix socket that can be used as the docker host. Next, update the docker `settings.json` with the following values:

```
{
    "docker.host": "unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock",
    "docker.dockerPath": "/usr/bin/podman"
}
```

Alternatively, you can search for the **Docker: Docker Path** and the **Docker: Host** section in the **Settings** and update their value.

On Linux, you can [identify the Podman socket](https://podman-desktop.io/docs/migrating-from-docker/using-the-docker_host-environment-variable#procedure) location by:

```bash
podman info --format '{{.Host.RemoteSocket.Path}}'
```

And the Podman CLI path using this command:

```bash
which podman
```

### Attach Terminal

Now, you can attach the terminal to the container. First, start the container then right-lick on it and select the **Attach Shell** option.

[image: attach_shell_to_docker_image]

You can quit from it by typing the `exit` command, then press any key to close the terminal.